# Apt Update: Unable to connect to deb.debian.org

Tags: debian, apt

I'm trying to update the system, but I'm getting an error:

```
sudo apt update
```

Output:

```
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (146.75.2.132). - connect (113: No route to host) Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-debug unstable-debug InRelease                                  
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-ports unstable InRelease                                        
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                      
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                              
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
Hit:6 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease                       
Hit:7 https://mx-packages.ip-connect.vn.ua/mx/repo bullseye InRelease                              
Hit:8 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
```

System:

```
Kernel: 5.10.0-13-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 
parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-13-amd64 
Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 tk: Gtk 3.24.24 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm 4.16.1 vt: 7 
dm: LightDM 1.26.0 Distro: MX-21.1_x64 Wildflower April 9  2022 
base: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

Comment: @roaima How to fix it?

Comment: You've not given us very much to work on. Do you have a network card? Are you using wired or wireless? Do you have an IP address? Is it a physical machine or a virtual one? Has it ever worked, and if so what's changed?

Answer (score 9):

You seem to be able to connect to `security.debian.org`, `mx-packages.ip-connect.vn.ua` and `repository.spotify.com`, but `deb.debian.org` fails.

```
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
  Could not connect to debian.map.fastlydns.net:80 (146.75.2.132). 
- connect (113: No route to host) Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:
```

From this part, you can see that `deb.debian.org` is an alias of `debian.map.fastlydns.net`, which then gets translated to IP address 146.75.2.132.

Let's see the relevant DNS records:

```
$ dig +noall +answer deb.debian.org
deb.debian.org.         3600    IN      CNAME   debian.map.fastlydns.net.
debian.map.fastlydns.net. 30    IN      A       151.101.246.132
```

This is a global DNS-based (and probably geolocation-assisted) load balancer in action. Note that my query got a different IP address for `debian.map.fastlydns.net` than yours, probably because the DNS server determined that this IP address would be the closest-to-me Debian mirror that is part of the load balancing scheme. The Debian mirror servers that are part of this scheme should be in communication with the load balancer system of fastlydns.net, reporting their status and current load levels.

Also, note that the Time-to-Live (TTL) values in the second column are quite short: 3600 seconds for the CNAME record on the first line, and just 30 seconds for the A record on the second line.

If we repeat the query, we should see the TTL numbers counting down:

```
$ dig +noall +answer deb.debian.org
deb.debian.org.         3208    IN      CNAME   debian.map.fastlydns.net.
debian.map.fastlydns.net. 29    IN      A       151.101.246.132

$ dig +noall +answer deb.debian.org
deb.debian.org.         3207    IN      CNAME   debian.map.fastlydns.net.
debian.map.fastlydns.net. 28    IN      A       151.101.246.132

$ dig +noall +answer deb.debian.org
deb.debian.org.         3206    IN      CNAME   debian.map.fastlydns.net.
debian.map.fastlydns.net. 27    IN      A       151.101.246.132

$ dig +noall +answer deb.debian.org
deb.debian.org.         3205    IN      CNAME   debian.map.fastlydns.net.
debian.map.fastlydns.net. 26    IN      A       151.101.246.132
```

This indicates the answers are coming from a caching DNS resolver server, and when the TTL value reaches zero, the caching resolver should expire the old data and get a fresh answer from the authoritative DNS server of the `map.fastlydns.net` domain. This gives the authoritative DNS server a chance to point you at a different mirror of `deb.debian.org` if it gets the information that the one you were given originally has a problem or is too busy.

So what can you do? Well, the first thing to try is simply wait a few minutes and try again. If you then get pointed to a different IP address, then it indicates the Debian mirror server you got on your first attempt was having a problem of some sort, the load balancer became aware of it and started redirecting any queries for `deb.debian.org` from your general area to the next closest Debian mirror server with free capacity.

If that does not happen, it might be a connectivity issue somewhere between the mirror server and your Internet Service Provider - in fact, the `No route to host` part in the error message suggests this might be the case. You could do a TCP-based traceroute to port 80 of the target IP address to perhaps see how far you can get before the missing route is detected:

```
$ sudo traceroute -T -p 80 146.75.2.132
```

If the last hostname in the output seems to be referring to your Internet Service Provider, then it might be worthwhile to contact your ISP's support and report a problem.

But if the last hostname refers to some big backbone communications provider (e.g. `Level3.net`), then the problem is further away from your ISP: if your ISP has multiple different backbone links, they might be able to change their routing to work around the break (in fact, that should happen automatically after a while). Other than that, there is very little your ISP can do in that case.

If the `deb.debian.org` seems to be unreachable to you for a long time, you might go to [the list of Debian mirrors](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list), pick one that's relatively close to you and reachable, and add a `sources.list` entry for it.

If you have the `netselect` package already installed, you could use the `netselect` command to automatically pick a good Debian mirror site for you, but if you don't have it installed and don't currently have a Debian media at hand, then installing it would be a bit of a "Catch-22" problem.

Comment: Well spotted; I'd missed the partial successful resolving

Comment: Beautiful answer